# Why do I have 2 little tree sprouts growing from one Lychee nut seed

Tags: fruit-trees

I have a Lychee seedling I started with moist paper towels. I've done 25 all together, though not all at the same time. They are all planted now. June 21st was my first 5, July 10th I planted my last 9. My question is this, out of the first 5 I planted one of my little trees looks like 2 trees are growing out of the soil. I know it's not the root system because I carefully checked. Anyone know what could cause this? Thank you for your time. Angie

Comment: Not to worry.  A single seed can sometimes produce...siamese twins?  Or you planted two viable germinating seeds close together.  At this point leave them be.  What is their environment, sun, soil type (potting soil I hope), what have you added, what are your goals, have you ever grown anything from seeds?  Where is it you live?  Do you plan to plant them out of doors?  Keep them in a pot?  Expect more 'plums'?  do you understand acclimation?  Fertilizer for the first up potting to a slightly larger pot? I remember Lychee plums dried and salted eating them like candy.

Comment: I live in Avon Park Florida. I have them in potting soil. I've made a greenhouse for them so they're protected from the wind. I put them in the yard daily so I can get them use to the sun. I don't put them directly in the sun, I put them in a shaded area that allows some sunlight through the trees. I only water them with water I get out of our creek. I plan on planting some in the ground and giving the rest away. I have a total of 24. Planted at different times. They just started to sprout above the soil, so they're not ready to replant. Any advice will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: This information sounds great, Angie.  You have a creek?  Oh so nice!  I imagine you have a 'dome' or plastic covering your seedlings?  Excellent if they are out of doors in the shade to protect them from wind and rodents!  Make sure they don't get any direct sun or they might get cooked.  You are correct, not close to transplanting them.  You sound like you've got great sound knowledge of plants.  If you have 24 out of 25 germinated and planted and growing? You've beaten the odds!  I am hoping they are planted in tiny pots now to be up potted to slightly larger? Then a bit of fertilizer?

Comment: I can take a picture of what I made to protect them. I have 3 gallon pots waiting and ready for my babies. My husband says I'm to attached to the seedlings. I admit I am, everyday like I said before I set them in the yard, and no I don't put them directly in the sun. It's shady with a little sun coming through. I keep a close eye on them,  I even talk to them. I ask them if they're thirsty like they're going to answer me. I had one seed that didn't  start to sprout like the rest of them,  but I couldn't throw it away so I planted it. I couldn't give up on it. Any advice is appreciated Stormy.

Comment: Stormy, I wanted to let you know that their greenhouse is made out of plastic. I can zip it up so nothing will get inside it. I put air holes in it. I even put a rubber mat made with holes so that my babies can drain properly. If you have any advice no matter what is appreciated. Every little bit helps. Thank you Stormy for the advice you've given me so far. I really do need every bit I can get. Thank you