# What to do when one seed sprouts two growths (polyembryonic?)?

Tags: seeds, growth

I bought a lemon from a "local" veggies/fruit store. It only had 3 seeds, which I decided to plant, recording all the process.
Procedure: Soaked and properly peel the seeds. Cut just a little of the end tip. Wrap the seeds in wet paper and inside a sealed container.
2 of the seeds where alright (like normal seeds, no irregularities) and one was small and was split in half once sprouted. *I have a picture of the three sprouted seeds, if you also want to check that out! It's a scrsht of a video.*

I planted them. I used 3 pots of different sizes to experiment a little. The broken small one in the smallest pot, the other 2 in a pot, one bigger than the other. After some weeks, I can see the following:

[image: Small broken seed and normal seed in medium pot]

[image: Normal seed in big pot]

Pic1: The broken small seed has a nice growth. The normal seed in the medium pot one has 2 growths? And of the same "quality" or at the same "stage" as the small splitted one in the small pot.

Pic2: Normal seed in the biggest pot. 1 growth, smaller than the other 2 seeds, it seems a bit slower but it also has one "branch" or leave coming out already.

I have read in some sites and here as well, about what to do. [Ref1](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/40908/why-do-i-have-2-little-tree-sprouts-growing-from-one-lychee-nut-seed) lychee, no answer, [Ref2](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/57522/two-growths-from-one-tomato-seed) tomatos, now I know about "polyembryonic". Should I cut one of the 2 "twins"? It's not like there are 2 seeds fighting for resources. Is it alright to assume that if 2 growths sprouted, it is also possible that the root system is also bigger to allow that?